# search_key as array in match function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Formulae shown below has been working for me for low number of cells to check:

`=if(iserror(match(C1;A1;0));
if(iserror(match(C2;A1;0));
if(iserror(match(C3;A1;0));
if(iserror(match(C4;A1;0));"no matches";D4);D3);D2);D1)`

But now I have much more entries in column C that I have to check if they match entry in column A. How can I do this without writing super long formulae using tons of "if's" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,0),"no matches")`

If you meant `fuzzy` vlookup, please try:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(D:D,REGEXMATCH(A1,C:C)),"no matches")`

---

As @pnuts mentioned, for your regional settings replace `,` with `;`:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(D:D;REGEXMATCH(A1;C:C));"no matches")`

Comment: @Max Makhrov it won't work because A1 contains large amounts of text and I need to know whether single words in C1,C2,C3,etc are used in A1

Comment: Does `match(C1;A1;0)` find  large amounts of text in A1? Please, give sheet sample.

Comment: @saint337 it seems you translated a function wrongly. `MATCH` doesn't work like that.  Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Max Makhrov Thank you, regexmatch was what I needed.